# Should I delete my recovery partition while installing a different OS?

Tags: laptop, partitioning

I have a laptop running a pre-installed copy of Windows 7. I'd like to install Windows 8.1 on it, erasing all the data I have on both C: and D: partitions. The laptop came with a hidden recovery partition, which I've used a couple of times to do a factory reset.

1. Should I delete my recovery partition while installing Windows 8.1? I'm intending to delete C: and D: and recreate them. I've heard recreating partitions is a good thing to do when installing a different OS.
2. What would happen if I recreated C: and D: but didn't touch the recovery partition? Would my system become less stable?
3. If I didn't delete the recovery partition, would I be able to use it after installing Windows 8.1? What would happen if I did? Would my system be downgraded to Windows 7?
4. Can I do a factory reset of Windows 8.1 if it wasn't pre-installed?

The thing I'm afraid of is that if I deleted the recovery partition and something went wrong during installation, I would be left with an empty hard drive and no OS whatsoever.

Comment: Use Macrium Reflect Free and make an image of the hard drive in case you want to revert at back to 7 and recovery partition any time, make the Macrium rescue disk also, you can boot off of it to restore the image to the hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delete the recovery partition ONLY if you have no intention to return to the old system.
2. No impact on system stability retaining the recovery partition
3. Yes you can use it and yes, you would be returned to Windows 7 again.
4. No, I do not think so (your system would go back to Windows 7). You can do a Windows 8 Reset however.

Now at this late date, Windows 8.1 is itself quite old. Consider moving to Windows 10 as it is a much better operating system.

You need to check the computer's ability to run Windows 10 or Windows 8 (about the same requirements).  The same answers above apply, but if the machine is too old, you may wish to / need to replace it.

Comment: Thanks. The laptop is quite old too (Intel i3, 3GB RAM). I'm afraid Windows 10 wouldn't run on it well.

Comment: True, but then Windows 8 requires the same requirements as Windows 10. So maybe stay on Windows 7 until you can replace it. I adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: Add more memory and it will run 10 just fine. 4gb min, 8gb is better.

Comment: Agree and that could definitely help.

Comment: I agree with the idea to go to Windows 10 rather than any other Windows version.

Comment: Good idea and you will be happy once it all works.